# Undo git rm -r cached

Tags: git

I am new to Git and I think I removed files on my local accidentaly. I used this command `git rm -r --cached .` and it removed the files. But I didn't commit it yet.

How can I undo it?

Comment: Kudos for stopping and asking what to do next. Most questions here on Stack Overflow in such a situation seems to keep going with "I added all my changes, committed, then did a force-push because git wouldn't let me push without it, now my repository is broken, HALP!". You, instead, stopped, and asked. So kudos for that, you're on the right path.

Answer (score 2):

[git rm documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rm#git-rm---cached) is kind of clear:

> **--cached**
>
> Use this option to unstage and remove paths only from the index. Working tree files, whether modified or not, will be left alone.

So if you lost files it's because there was already commits existing on the repository (not yours, but others ones).

Try to run **`git reset`** it should clear all your not committed actions, so you should find the repository like it was before this.

Comment: pssst... loose /= lose

Comment: @evolutionxbox psst, [thanks!](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/48004072/revisions)

Answer (score 0):

The index contains a path and an object id.  `git rm --cached` erases the index entry, undoing the act means putting it back the way it was.

If the content was unchanged since checkout, `git reset -- path/to/it` is your ticket.  If you `git add`ed the content, it's in the repository but the association between path and content is lost, you can find objects in `.git/objects` created about the right time and `git show` them to find the right one, then `git update-index --add --cacheinfo 10644,objectidhere,path/to/it` to restore the index entry manually.

edit: or if you haven't edited the content in your worktree since `git checkout` or any later `git add`, then just `git add` it again.